# finding rank with two columns oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

i have the following query to find the rank

```
SELECT a.appName,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY a.appName, b.depName ORDER BY a.appName) 
as RANK,b.depName,Count(distinct a.userName) as visitors FROM tbl_app_webstats a 
inner join tbl_users b on  b.userName = a.userName 
where a.date_time between '01-JUN-12' and '20-JUN-14' and a.appName like '%' 
group by a.appName,b.depName order by a.appName;
```

but it is giving me incorrect result

```
appName            RANK  depName   visitors
app1                1     dep1      1
app1                1     dep2      1
app1                1     dep3      2
app2                1     dep1      3
app2                1     dep2      1
app2                1     dep3      5
app3                1     dep2      2
app3                1     dep5      8
app4                1     dep1      2
app4                1     dep5      13
app5                1     dep5      2
```

the result sholuld be like this

```
appName            RANK  depName   visitors
app1                1     dep1      1
app1                2     dep2      1
app1                3     dep3      2
app2                1     dep1      3
app2                2     dep2      1
app2                3     dep3      5
app3                1     dep2      2
app3                2     dep5      8
app4                1     dep1      2
app4                2     dep5      13
app5                1     dep5      2
```

any idea what might be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query:

```
SELECT a.appName,
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY a.appName ORDER BY b.depName) 
as RANK,
b.depName,Count(distinct a.userName) as visitors FROM tbl_app_webstats a 
inner join tbl_users b on  b.userName = a.userName 
where a.date_time between '01-JUN-12' and '20-JUN-14' and a.appName like '%' 
group by a.appName,b.depName order by a.appName;
```

**EDIT:** To get top 10 ranks

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT a.appName,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY a.appName ORDER BY b.depName) 
    as RANK,
    b.depName,Count(distinct a.userName) as visitors FROM tbl_app_webstats a 
    inner join tbl_users b on  b.userName = a.userName 
    where a.date_time between '01-JUN-12' and '20-JUN-14' and a.appName like '%' 
    group by a.appName,b.depName order by a.appName
) WHERE RANK <=10
order by appName;
```

Comment: thanks its working what if i wanted to find out top 10 ranked department for each app

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT a.appName,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY a.appName ORDER BY b.depName) 
......
```

You could also do this:

```
SELECT a.appName,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.appName ORDER BY b.depName)
......
```

To address you comment. You could do something like this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY appName ORDER BY depName) AS Rank
    ....
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    CTE
WHERE
    CTE.Rank<=10;
```

Answer (score 1):

You Want TOP 10 Means using CTE Method.
Try to **partition Single column a.appName only**

Suppose you use partition Two Column means(

```
app1                     dep1      =1st Statement Combination is 1
app1                     dep2      =2nd Statement Combination is 1
app1                     dep3      =3rd Statement Combination is 1



  With CTE(A_Name,A_Rank,A_DepName,A_Visitor)
  AS
  (

    SELECT a.appName,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY a.appName  ORDER BY a.appName) 
    as RANK,b.depName,Count(distinct a.userName) as visitors FROM tbl_app_webstats a 
    inner join tbl_users b on  b.userName = a.userName 
    where a.date_time between '01-JUN-12' and '20-JUN-14' and a.appName like '%' 
    group by a.appName,b.depName order by a.appName
)
Select * from CTE where A_Rank <=10
```